# Package JSON For Karma and Jasmine Installation

Tags: json, karma-runner

I am reading a book (AngularJS) and currently I am on the step where I need to install Karma Test runner and Jasmine plugin. I actually understand (because it is well described) every step of the installation, but getting stuck on the Package JSON file.

The problem is, that I have no ANY idea what is this file for, where to find it, where the file should be downloaded from and placed in. I cannot find any useful information, where it is explained, why do I need this file and where do get it from.

I found some articles explaining how to create the file, however I don't know what to write in it's version or name and so on...

Could anyone help me with this some step by step explanation about the file, or share a reference where I can get little more information about it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package.json file is metadata that describes a Node Package Mananger package for the benefit of other people downloading that package. It should be placed in the root directory of your project. It lists the sort of information you would expect to find when searching for a package, such as title, description, author, version number etc. [A full explanation can be found here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Most importantly it also lists the production and development dependencies required for your module to run, any npm package listed here would be automtically downloaded with the package (dev dependencies downloaded when --dev flag set). Dependencies required for your package to run would be listed under "dependencies", dependencies required for developers working on your code would be listed under "devDependencies"

If you are not planning on releasing your work as a node module for others to download then you don't need to worry about the majority of the fields because
nobody will ever see it.

However the package.json file is very useful even if you aren't planning on releasing as a package, because it provides an automated way of fetching dependencies for your project.
Any listed dependencies will be installed automatically into a folder called "node_modules" in the root of your project by Visual Studio 2013 update 3 onwards.
Running the command "npm install" against the root of your project would also have the same effect, automatically fetching and installing any listed dependencies.

So for example to provide an automated way for developers working on your code to fetch modules such as Karma you would have the following in your package.json:

```
// package.json
{
"devDependencies": {
  "karma": "^0.13.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.23",      
  "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8"
 }
}
```